# How do I separate an illustration by colors in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I have a large illustration with several groups and subgroups of objects. I want to flatten everything and separate the whole illustration by colors. I tried merging the artwork into one layer and clicking trim but nothing got trimmed. I also tried flattening the artwork and clicking trim but nothing happened. Am I supposed to use another tool in the Pathfinder? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here, also it seems like you have multiple questions here. Can you please do your best to clarify and break up your questions?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the question. I'm just trying to separate an illustration by color. But it's a complex illustration with many groups and subgroups so I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: I still vaguely understand, I have to keep on rereading trying to clarify. If you could be more specific as well as adding screenshots, it would help a lot.

Comment: Maybe I'm needlessly over-explaining it. It's pretty simple. I made an illustration and it has a lot of groups and subgroups of layers. I want to separate the entire illustration by colors. Once I separate by colors, I plan on putting each color in its own respective layer labeled 'blue' 'pink' etc...

Comment: Are you able to ungroup everything or would that not work for what you need? Can you include a screenshot too?

Comment: I can ungroup everything but it will take a long time with so many groups and subgroups within subgroups. Probably not the most efficient way to work on Illustrator lol. I can't include a screenshot right now unfortunately.

Comment: @Desi you can select everything and keep hitting ctrl shift G until everything is ungrouped. Even with twenty nested groups ist still just 20 keystorkes.

Comment: FYI `Trim` won't often have any immediately noticeable *visual* change. `Trim` will alter the structure of objects and how they overlap/interact. It won't change the visuals in 99.9% of instances.

Answer (score 2):

***If*** *I understand correctly*, you need to "ungroup all" repeatedly, assuming you've already used pathfinder to subtract shapes as necessary for overlaps and knockouts to look correct once you've layered by colour.

Once you've done these two steps, then select one element of colour XX, go to **Select>Same>Fill Colour**, and using the layers palette, pull your elements into the new target layer.

Bear in mind you ***could*** *also* do this *without ungrouping* by using the **Direct Select** (White Arrow) tool for the initial selection (being careful to select the whole item versus the segment or anchor point of course) and then completing the same **Select>Same>Fill Colour** workflow.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is not a new answer. I'm kind of being silenced due to lack of reputation, but I thought I should add how brilliant the answer provided by @GerardFalla is: it absolutely works, saved me tons of time, and is more precise than painstaking selection, which can often be laden with mistakes.